# Getting fetch response, and adding to app without refreshing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am adding an item via a PUT fetch, and I the only way I can see it appear is if I refresh the page (and it comes from a fetch GET).

However, I would like it to add immediately. I would like it to add the response form the API to the state.

I tried doing this with

`.then((res) => res.json()).then((item) => this.props.addItem(item))`.

Then tried rendering it with my main component but was not successful. I do not get errors.

`<PhotoGalleryLevel {...props} addItem={(item) => this.setState({ tags: [item].concat(this.state.tags)})}>`

I put all my [code in a codepen here](http://codepen.io/yarnball/pen/jVbbpy).

Here is where I do the fetch:

```
var PhotoGalleryLevel = React.createClass({
  getDefaultProps: function(){
    return {
      level: 1
    }
  },
    handleSubmit1: function(e, value) {
    e.preventDefault();
     return fetch('localhost:8000/createapi', {
     method: 'POST',
     body: JSON.stringify({
      'name':this.state.tagname,
      'taglevel':this.props.level}
      )
      })
      .then((res) => res.json()).then((item) => this.props.addItem(item))
      .catch((err) => console.error(err))
  },
  onChange(e) { 
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
  },
  displayChildren: function () {
    const { children } = this.props;
    return React.Children.map(children, function(child) {
      if(child.type.displayName == this.constructor.displayName) {
        return React.cloneElement(child, {
          ...this.props,
          children: child.props.children,
          level: this.props.level+1,
        });
      }
      return child;
    }.bind(this));
  },
  render: function () {
    var getCategoriesForLevel = this.props.displayedCategories.some(function (tag) {
      return tag.taglevel === this.props.level;
    }.bind(this));
    var filteredTags = this.props.tags.filter(function (tag) {
      return tag.taglevel === this.props.level;
    }.bind(this));
    return (
              <div>
        <div className="filter-panel">
           <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit1}>
              <input name="tagname" type="text" placeholder={'Add L' + this.props.level} onChange={this.onChange} />
            </form>
          {filteredTags.map(function (tag, index){
            return <PhotoGalleryButton buttonElement={'a'} className={'test1'} key={index} tag={tag} selectTag={this.props.selectTag} />;
          }.bind(this))}
        </div>
        {this.displayChildren()}
     </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: You need to update state of component to update view, try using getInitialState to init all the data, than render everything from state and on fetching just update state and react will update view. Hope this helps.

Comment: `getInitialState` on which? I have added the getInitialState on line 77, then called it on line 128 on the render (http://codepen.io/yarnball/pen/jVbbpy). Still no success

Answer (score 0):

I can be wrong, but the my idea is to render it from state, something like this:

```
var PhotoGalleryLevel = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    var tags = this.props.tags.filter(function (tag) {
      return tag.taglevel === this.props.level;
    }.bind(this));

    return {
      tags: tags
    };
  },
  getDefaultProps: function(){
    return {
      level: 1
    }
  },
  handleSubmit1: function(e, value) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return fetch('localhost:8000/createapi', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        'name':this.state.tagname,
        'taglevel':this.props.level
      })
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((item) => this.setState({ tags: [item].concat(this.state.tags)}))
      .catch((err) => console.error(err))
  },
  onChange(e) { 
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
  },
  displayChildren: function () {
    const { children } = this.props;
    return React.Children.map(children, function(child) {
      if(child.type.displayName == this.constructor.displayName) {
        return React.cloneElement(child, {
          ...this.props,
          children: child.props.children,
          level: this.props.level+1,
        });
      }
      return child;
    }.bind(this));
  },
  render: function () {
    // let className
    // let buttonElement
    var getCategoriesForLevel = this.props.displayedCategories.some(function (tag) {
      return tag.taglevel === this.props.level;
    }.bind(this));
// switch(this.props.level) {
    return (
              <div>
        <div className="filter-panel">
                          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit1}>
                    <input name="tagname" type="text" placeholder={'Add L' + this.props.level} onChange={this.onChange} />
                </form>
          {this.state.tags.map(function (tag, index){
            return <PhotoGalleryButton buttonElement={'a'} className={'test1'} key={index} tag={tag} selectTag={this.props.selectTag} />;
          }.bind(this))}
        </div>
        {this.displayChildren()}
     </div>
    );
  }
});
```

But keep in mind that:

This is a bad practice - "Using props to generate state in getInitialState often leads to duplication of "source of truth", i.e. where the real data is." - http://reactjs.cn/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html

Comment: Thanks but this is not rendering the value from the fetch. Also not getting an error. Is there something I should be doing in my return (line 128 http://codepen.io/yarnball/pen/jVbbpy)?